# does LEN() have bug?

Tags: sql-server

It seems that LEN() ignores whitespaces at the right side of a variable.

```sql
declare @a varchar(100)

set @a = 'John   '

print len(@a)
```

The above code prints 4 whereas it should be 7.

Is this a bug?

Comment: varchar trims trailing spaces.

Comment: The interesting point is, if you use something like replace(@a, ' ', '$'), you'll get a 'John$$$' value. So, the whitespaces are really there!

Comment: For full explanation, see [Behavior of Varchar with spaces at the end](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/behavior-of-varchar-with-spaces-at-the-end) on our sister site https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @lptr  Not a valid test with the concatination.  datalength() is not the same as len()  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=875b1ab5f4c4a78a0d253b7b95a41ca7

Comment: I don't think there's any confusion or dispute with spaces and varchar data types, it was purely the output of `len()` that confused the OP but it's clearly documented behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug, this is the intended behavior. To quote [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql):

> `LEN` excludes trailing spaces. If that is a problem, consider using the [`DATALENGTH` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql) function which does not trim the string

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But, I don't think DATALENGTH is a correct answer.
DATALENGTH() returns the number of bytes that a string consumes in memory. For VARCHAR() type it works fine, but for NVARCHAR() type it returns twice as much as the number of characters in a given string. So, DATALENGTH will not report a correct answer always.

Answer (score 1):

Not a bug, is [right there in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the official documentation. It is expected behaviour. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you folks,

I really didn't know that LEN() ignores trailing spaces!

I think DATALENGTH() does not return a correct answer always.

For NVARCHAR() type it returns twice the number of characters in a string. In fact, it returns the total number of bytes that the string consumes in memory.

In my opinion in order to get the correct length of a string value, we should use a formula like below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Length(@x NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (CASE WHEN RIGHT(@x, 1) = ' ' THEN LEN(REPLACE(@x, ' ', '$')) ELSE LEN(@x) END)
END
```

The function is not efficient. I know. But, it returns a correct answer at least.